# How can I set up a parameter as an attribute drop down menu on a script tool?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, parameters

I have built a script tool in ArcGIS Pro and I would like to set up one parameter as a drop down menu (the options in the drop down menu should be all the attribute values of one of the map layers).

I can't seem to find the right 'Data type' to pick up. If I choose 'Layer' as 'Data Type' and I run the tool I get a drop down menu with all map layers. I'm looking for something similar but specific to a layer field. If I choose 'field' in 'Data Type' and I run the tool absolutely nothing happens. What is this 'field' referring to? How could I achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: I have had a look at that link and I'm afraid my level of python is not good enough to understand what is said in "http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/programming-a-toolvalidator-class.htm". So, can I only do what I'm trying to do from the 'Validation' section? Can I not do it from the 'Parameters' section?